# ng-model variable not updating when DOM element changes

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-ngmodel

I am making a website using AngularJS.

I have declared variables in jade as:

```
div {{event.latitude}} {{event.longitude}}
      input#latitude(type='number' name='latitude' ng-model='event.latitude' required) 
      input#longitude(type='number' name='longitude' ng-model='event.longitude' required)
```

On the same page, I am using Google Maps. I am updating the above variables in JavaScript like this:

```
// adds a listener for when the user clicks the map
      map.addListener('click', function(event){

        // gets lat/long position from where the user clicked
        var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
        var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // sets the event marker to where the user clicked
        eventLocation.setPosition(latlng);

        console.log('Event Location:\n' , latitude, longitude);

        document.getElementById('latitude').value = latitude;
        document.getElementById('longitude').value = longitude;
      });
```

This code works. When I click the map, that latitude and longitude are updated in the form input boxes.

However, the problem I am running in to is that the ng-model variable is not updating. As shown above, I am displaying the ng-model variables via interpolation. However, they only display a value when I manually click in the input boxes and change the values myself. They do not update when the javascript changes the value of the input.

Can anyone point out to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event listener attached via `addListener` will not automatically trigger AngularJS' digest cycle for you.

Since the digest cycle doesn't start, no watchers will execute, no changes will be detected and the UI won't be updated.

Use `$apply`:

```
map.addListener('click', function(event) {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.event.longitude = 100;
    scope.event.latitude = 50;
  });
});
```

I assumed you have an `event` object on your scope since you are using the binding `{{event.longitude}}`.

You shouldn't really need `document.getElementById('latitude').value = latitude;` unless you are using it for something else that isn't apparent in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Any thing that is out of the context of angularJS would not affect $scope,so as you can not get value in ng-model.

but Still if you want to do it you have to wrap your code in side the context of Angularjs(Best practise is to crate a custom directive)
and in the end you have to call

`$scope.$digest()`.